# Post-receive hook to pull from bare repo

Tags: git

On our server we have, for each project, 2 folders: /repository and /htdocs. Htdocs being a clone of repository, which is the bare repo. Every developer has his own repository clone to work in. htdocs is there to preview the project to project managers.

I would like to set up a post-receive hook that automatically updates htdocs when updates are pushed from the developers.

I have following in my post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=../htdocs git pull origin master
```

However, when I push, I see following error: [image: git error]

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Note that

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=../htdocs git checkout -f
```

works, but this is kinda slow (as the project is pretty big). It is also possible someone made some bugfixes in htdocs that would get lost with `checkout -f` if they weren't committed.

Comment: you say your "preview" repo is in /htdocs, but you set your git_work_tree to "../site_now" -- that makes no sense; you'll have to explain in a bit more detail (Update: the post has been corrected, this comment is moot)

Comment: regarding your update: no changes should be made to such a preview directory, just as general advice

Comment: Made a wrong copy/paste, updated the code the work trees should be htdocs indeed. Makes sense as well that you shouldn't work in the preview dir, I guess.

Comment: Then checkout would work well for you ;)
But checkout will not get the updates that were committed to the bare repo, so a fetch would still be necessary. And regarding "slowness": a pull would do something like that checkout (a merge, which includes updating the working tree), so I don't think that'd give you much of an advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 GIT_WORK_TREE=../htdocs GIT_DIR=../htdocs/.git git pull origin master
```

If you don't specify GIT_DIR, git believe the repo is still "`repository`" (the bare repo), which might not have a remote named "`origin`" (hence the error message).