# Need for a bare repo in GIT

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, egit

While reading the tutorials I keep hearing that I need to create something known as a bare repository for sharing all the files in the repo.

I also hear that a bare repo does not contain any of the worfiles.

If it does not have any workfiles then what will the other users clone on their local machines???

I currently have a directory in my linux server which i need to share among several users which will be accessing through eclipse ide's.

Can anyone explain the issues highlighted above in plain words.

Comment: Have you read [Getting Git on a Server](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)?

Comment: Yes but I'm not getting the concept of bare repo and its requirement.

Answer (score 3):

> While reading the tutorials I keep hearing that I need to create something known as a bare repository for sharing all the files in the repo.

When you `git push` to a remote repository, you can overwrite the files in the `working directory`. To avoid this, you can use a `bare` repository, which doesn't even have a `working directory`.

However, because there's no `working directory`, you can't work *in* the `bare` repo, you can only `push` to it and `pull` from it. This makes it ideal as a "collection point" or "collaboration repo" for multiple users -- which is why the `git` tutorials say to use a `bare` repository for servers.

A normal `git` repo looks like this:

```
my-repository/
    .git/
        COMMIT_EDITMSG 
        ORIG_HEAD
        description    
        index
        objects
        FETCH_HEAD     
        branches       
        gitk.cache     
        info           
        refs
        HEAD           
        config         
        hooks          
        logs
    file1
    file2
```

`my-repository` is the `working directory`, containing the files you work on `file1`, `file2` etc. All the `git` data is stored in the `.git` folder.

On a `bare` repository, you don't have a working folder. All you have is the contents of the `.git` folder, stored in the top-level of that repository:

```
my-bare-repository/
    COMMIT_EDITMSG 
    ORIG_HEAD
    description    
    index
    objects
    FETCH_HEAD     
    branches       
    gitk.cache     
    info           
    refs
    HEAD           
    config         
    hooks          
    logs
```

This is what other users clone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I got the points you made.I also have another directory containing actual files which I want others to checkout.Now what do i need to do?

Comment: @gautamvegeta: (1) Commit those files to a repository.  (2) Push the commit to a public repository.  (3) Tell other users to clone/pull from the public repository.

Comment: I have heard something known that I need post-receive hooks what are they and how do I set up those.Here I have heard that I can clone my actual repo containing workfiles using this post-receive hook through this bare repo.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: Please stop posting the same question in multiple places.

Comment: @gautamvegeta This is no longer about the question - read [this book](http://git-scm.com/book). It **really** helped me learn about `git`. And it has pretty pictures. If you've got specific questions about `post-hooks` etc, ask in a separate question :)

Answer (score 2):

> I also hear that a bare repo does not contain any of the workfiles.

Yes it is.

A remote repository is generally a bare repository — a Git repository that has no working directory. All data is stored in `.git` directory and working directory is not needed. It is just a collaboration point.

> If it does not have any workfiles then what will the other users clone
>   on their local machines???

Data from `.git` directory will be cloned.

Comment: What do i need to do if I want the users to check out the actual folder which has the actual contents through this bare repo.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: The method is the same for cloning from bare and non-bare repositories.  Users do not need special instructions, an ordinary `git clone` works for both.

Comment: I have heard something known that I need post-receive hooks what are they and how do I set up those.Here I have heard that I can clone my actual repo containing workfiles using this post-receive hook through this bare repo.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: Why do you need post-receive hooks?

Comment: I got the feeling that I need to create something known as post-receive hooks which would link the bare repo and actual repo containing workfiles.So when other users would push their changes to the project it would inturn update the actaul repo.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: No, you don't need post-receive hooks.  You will typically only push to bare repos, so there is no working copy to update.

Comment: So If i want to share to the team a folder which is consisting of actaul work files how can I do it?

Comment: @gautamvegeta: This is covered in any Git tutorial.  To share the contents of a folder, (1) commit the files, (2) push to a public repository, (3) ask the team to pull/clone the repository.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: Think of these three steps as (1) save your changes (2) publish the work (3) download it.

Comment: So what is the post-receive hook used for?May be I've mixed up a lot.Is the post-receive hook relevant at all?

Comment: I also saw a question with the subject "Post-receive hook to pull from bare repo" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878583/post-receive-hook-to-pull-from-bare-repo?rq=1

Comment: @gautamvegeta: You can do anything you want in a hook.  A hook is just a place for you to put a script that Git will run at a specific time.  You don't need a hook, it is entirely your decision if you want a hook, and it is your decision what the hook does.

Comment: Say If i wanted to do it this way how can I do it?

Comment: If bare reo is just a collaborating point what to what files is it collaborating to?